# pinning a :i386 package

Tags: 32-bit, pinning

I have gcc-4.7 installed from the *ubuntu-toolchain-r ppa*. Since gcc-4.8 was recently added to that ppa, I've run into a problem. Acroread wants `libstdc++6:i386`, but I can't figure out how to pin that to gcc-4.7.

If I run `apt-cache policy` I get this:

```
 apt-cache policy libstdc++6:i386
libstdc++6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
     4.8.0-3ubuntu3~12.04 0
        -10 http://our-mirror.example.com/repository/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://our-mirror.example.com/repository/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

Anyone know how to pin a i386 package?